# How to remove MDM from iPad iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-device-management

I bought an iPad, the user had removed the iCloud in front of me. But he did not remove the MDM profile from the iPad.

She did the full reset on the iPad, however the MDM profile is still there how can I remove that or should I return the device?

Answer (score 2):

Open general, swipe up on the right side, find Profiles & Device Management and tap it.

Tap each of the profiles in turn and delete them. The MDM profile should show "Remove Management" in red and explain what it will do. The others should say "Delete Profile"

When that's done, you should have a clean device that you could erase all content and settings. Then see that the device isn't tied to a corporate Device Enrollment system. In that case, you'd want to return the iPad or get a bill of sale indicating that the device will be released from "corporate" control in a period of time.

The DEP can be under education or business - so the steps they take will be similar to release that serial number and not re-enroll it in the MDM each time the device is configured/activated.

- https://www.apple.com/business/dep/

Comment: is there any method to check that the device (ipad) in enrolled (DEP) before you reset it?

Answer (score 0):

The device could be set up in DEP to the company it belonged to. In which case, they'd have to remove the DEP profile in their MDM. Even then, apple would still show that it belongs to them unless they contact apple and let them know that they sold it.

Answer (score -1):

If your iPad is locked with another users Apple ID there is no way to remove that profile yourself. The user that you purchased the iPad from will need to remove their Apple ID from that device. That user can login to iCloud and remove that device from their profile. You will then be able to setup your iPad.
[How to remove the device from iCloud](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2702?locale=en_US)

Comment: It is not locked. I had last user sign out from the iCloud and factory reset the device in front of me. Only thing is the device is still managed by MDM software.

Comment: Go to Settings > General > Profiles > Click on the remaining MDM profile > Remove > Remove again