# How to get rid of supervision

Tags: ipad

So, I today I went into my settings to see that my iPad is being supervised by some school. I don’t even go to this school, I had to look it up to realize it was a school, and they don’t even own this iPad. I certainly know this was not there before,I don’t know how long it has been in supervision for but I’ve only now seen it. I looked up how to remove the supervision and I was told to factory reset my iPad so I tried but it is telling me that there was an “error connecting to the Apple ID server”. I’ve realized just now that this happened like 10 min ago as my WiFi stopped working out of no where and it is asking me to put in the password for the WiFi which is strange. I don’t know if it has restricted anything but I sure don’t want them controlling my iPad.

Comment: A device that’s enrolled in some sort of management tool/program must have been owned or in possession by that organization.  How did you acquire your iPad?

Comment: I got it on my birthday, I’m pretty sure it was from a third party seller we commonly buy from and it was brand new. We usually never have any problems with the devices but it did not come being managed by a school. I’m starting to connect the dotes because a couple of months ago this app called manager installed on my iPad on its own and at first I thought it was an Apple app but it wasn’t but I couldn’t delete it so I just kept it there and now I see that my iPad is being supervised.

Comment: See bmike's answer below.  That device was enrolled at some point.  In the future, only purchase Apple devices from authorized sources.

Answer (score 4):

The serial number may be claimed - correctly or incorrectly, you have two options.

1. If you can get to settings see if you can determine the exact address of the management server (get screenshots) and then [try to remove the profiles](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/226978/5472).
2. If that doesn’t work, you have to handle this administratively with the [School](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/374924/5472) and/or [Apple](https://support.apple.com/). Collect all your receipts for purchase so you can help clarify how you came into possession of a device that’s marked as school owned.

Answer (score 0):

Supervision is generally done during the DEP process.  It can't be easily undone/removed.  The reseller, or possibly the org who returned the device, will have to release it from MDM via Apple Business Manager, at which point you'll have to erase/reinstall iOS or possibly use DFU mode if that option is locked.

After that, during set up you will not be prompted for MDM enrollment, and it should be free from any management.

Until this is done, any number of operations can be remotely performed on the device by the organization or person managing the MDM instance (e.g. locking it, pushing settings, etc.).